# Nginx on docker, curl get Connection refused

Tags: php, docker, nginx, curl, docker-compose

I am working in a local environment with docker.
I have an nginx web container and a php container which are in the same network.

I build the php container from my own dockerfile (with phpfpm and phpcli); and, the nginx I compose it in a docker-compose from the `nginx:stable` hub image.

I have 2 projects: a symfony(`http://i-r4y.kaiza.lh/`) and a drupal(`http://i-z4r4.kaiza.lh/`) which runs in it. and the symfony exposes an api which have to be consumed by the drupal. The problem is that an error when I call the symfony from the drupal `cURL error 7: Failed to connect to i-r4y.kaiza.lh port 80: Connection refused`

I thought it was a configuration of the symfony side api route; like it must be public or accept CORS etc ...

but when I enter on bash **in the php container**, and I do curl either the symfony or drupal url, I have the same error.

```
app@kz-php74:/var/www$ curl http://i-r4y.kaiza.lh
curl: (7) Failed to connect to i-r4y.kaiza.lh port 80: Connection refused
app@kz-php74:/var/www$ curl http://i-z4r4.kaiza.lh
curl: (7) Failed to connect to i-z4r4.kaiza.lh port 80: Connection refused
```

I checked in the php container that the hosts are present in `/etc/hosts`

```
app@kz-php74:/var/www$ cat /etc/hosts | grep i-
127.0.0.1   i-r4y.kaiza.lh
127.0.0.1   i-z4r4.kaiza.lh
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  php7.4:
    build:
      context: ../../../dockerfile
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.php
      args:
        PHP_VERSION: 7.4
    container_name: "kz-php74"
    hostname: "kz-php74"
    user: 1000:1000
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - "${LOCAL_PATH}/../www:/var/www"
    extra_hosts:
      - "i-r4y.kaiza.lh:127.0.0.1"
      - "i-z4r4.kaiza.lh:127.0.0.1"
    networks:
      - kz_local

  mysql:
    container_name: kz-mysql
    image: mariadb:10.4.0
    volumes:
      - ${LOCAL_PATH}/.data/mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${LOCAL_PATH}/config/mariadb/conf.d/custom.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/custom.cnf
      - ${LOCAL_PATH}/../www:/var/www
    ports:
      - ${MYSQL_PORT:-3306}:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - kz_local

  web:
    image: nginx:stable
    container_name: kz-web
    volumes:
      - ${LOCAL_PATH}/config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ${LOCAL_PATH}/../www:/var/www
    ports:
      - 80:80
    networks:
      - kz_local

networks:
  kz_local:
    external: true
```

The nginx config of drupal:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name i-z4r4.kaiza.lh;

    root /var/www/i-z4r4/web;

    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
    
    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }

    # In Drupal 8, we must also match new paths where the '.php' appears in
    # the middle, such as update.php/selection. The rule we use is strict,
    # and only allows this pattern with the update.php front controller.
    # This allows legacy path aliases in the form of
    # blog/index.php/legacy-path to continue to route to Drupal nodes. If
    # you do not have any paths like that, then you might prefer to use a
    # laxer rule, such as:
    #   location ~ \.php(/|$) {
    # The laxer rule will continue to work if Drupal uses this new URL
    # pattern with front controllers other than update.php in a future
    # release.
    location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
        set $fastcgi_pass "kz-php74:9000";

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
        # Security note: If you're running a version of PHP older than the
        # latest 5.3, you should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini.
        # See http://serverfault.com/q/627903/94922 for details.
        include fastcgi_params;
        # Block httpoxy attacks. See https://httpoxy.org/.
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass $fastcgi_pass;
    }

  ...

    upstream php {
        server kz-php74:8080;
    }
}
```

For symfony:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name i-r4y.kaiza.lh;

    root /var/www/i-r4y/public;

    resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        set $fastcgi_pass "kz-php74:9000";

        fastcgi_pass $fastcgi_pass;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }
...
    upstream php {
        server kz-php74:8080;
    }
...
}
```

will anyone have any idea why this is not working?

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure the `docker inspect` screenshots are of help here. If you have a **docker-compose.yml** file you should paste its content here, same for your **cURL** command. You said they are in the same network, have you tried to ping one from the other ?

Comment: I put the screenshot on the docker-compose and the curl error. I left the screenshots of the docker inspect to show that they are on the same network 'kz_local'.

Comment: Ok no, I often do updates of questions but this is a bit too much: delete all the screenshots and paste some text in the question. To write a code block, use `\`\`\`` on a first line, then your code, and close it with `\`\`\`` again.

Comment: Try targetting the container with its service name instead, that's easier, and reliable: `curl web`

Comment: ha, when I do that 'curl kz-web' I have something: the symfony html. but the problem is that I have to call it from the application side (drupal); so i need the url call to work (not a container name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding an alias in the network of the web container through which I can access from the php container.

```
...
  web:
    image: nginx:stable
    ....
    networks:
      kz_local:
        # To allow fetch (call, curl) from php container.
        aliases:
          - api.i-r4y.kaiza.lh
          - api.i-z4r4.kaiza.lh
...
```

and of course, I needed to add the url aliases in config nginx :

```
...
server_name i-z4r4.kaiza.lh api.i-z4r4.kaiza.lh;
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to expose port 80 to your docker host.

It looks like you are trying to curl from your docker host (your real machine running docker) to nginx running in a docker container.

You can do that in docker-compose with the following:

```
web:
  image: nginx:stable
  …
  ports: 
    - 80:80
```

This will get you to nginx. However, your next obstacle will probably be ngxinx reaching your php service.

Like @AmyDev mentioned, you'll be better served using docker's name resolution for that.

In your nginx config, you need the following line to point nginx at docker's internal DNS:

```
resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
```

Then you can declare your `upstream` with the following:

```
upstream php {
    # use the docker service name. I removed the . b/c I don't know if that works in a docker service name
    # This assumes the docker service has been renamed from php7.4 to php74 in docker-compose.yml
    server php74:8080; # or whatever port to which php is listening
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i tried what you said but it still doesn't work. i put my nginx configs in my post. if you can help me more precisely, please ^^ thx

Comment: in fact, in the web container, url curls work fine. but the problem is with the php container.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `curl http://i-r4y.kaiza.lh` you make a request to the same container (php7.4), not on `web` (nginx). If you want to make request to another container, you can use the container service name as domain.

Try running `curl http://web` in the php container

Comment: Thank you for your answer. indeed, the direct call between container name is possible and works perfectly. The problem is the call of url alias nginx from the php container.